# unable to get sum of values in a column of dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to write a code in python to sum the values of a feature in pandas. the data inside the feature are say 55, 60, 8, 15 and the name of the feature is say age_col. the age_col.sum() gives following result. 
           5560815
using for loop as

```
for i in range(len(age_col)):
     sum += age_col[i]
```

gives following error

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" dtype returns data type 'object'.

I also used all the methods to convert it into float or numeric value.

Please help

Comment: Thank you. I used this conversion but the same error appears.

Comment: I used "age_col.astype('float64', error='raise', inplace=True)"

Comment: Use `age_col = pd.to_numeric(age_col, errors='coerce')`

Comment: Thanks  jezrael, still unable t solve the problem. now i am getting new error "KeyError: 33"

Comment: Not understand, `pd.to_numeric(age_col, errors='coerce').sum()` not working ?